# tensorflow install from sources bazel error

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

As I am having an error "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GRUCell'" when tried to run transate.py i removed tensorflow from my system and started installing it again from sources. I installed bazel and configured the installation. After "Build the pip package", I am getting the following error.

Can anyone please help me in resolving these errors

Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: Simply because the wheel file is not existent.

Comment: Can u please tell me in which folder should I put the wheel file and from where should I download it?

Comment: You don't need to download it. Just following the instructions here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux. You just pass an url instead of a local path to pip command.

Comment: Which URL should I pass and on which command?

Answer (score 1):

The error says "cannot stat 'bazel-bin/.../build_pip_package.runfiles/tensorflow'" meaning your runfiles tree doesn't exist or is unreadable. This indicates something went wrong during the build, particularly the runfiles tree creation step. The "runfiles tree" is a directory tree that contains the files that the binary you built needs at runtime, and the root of it is the "bazel-bin/.../build_pip_package.runfiles" directory.

This suspicion of mine is also backed up by the hanging runfiles tree creation actions in your output (on the top of the image), which is supposed to create this directory structure, and should *definitely* not take 11 hours, it should complete within a few seconds to a few minutes. (If any action hangs for more than a few minutes that's already a sign something's likely wrong.)

Some questions:

- If you rerun the build, does it hang? In other words, is this problem deterministic or did it occur just once?
- What if you run the build like `bazel --output_user_root=/usr/local/foo build <whatever>`? You can use any other path that's on the local filesystem. What i'm poking at is, whether your output root was on NFS or a filesystem that got unmounted mid-build.